# How to Reduce Parameters in CloudFormation Parent Stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to follow AWS CloudFormation best practices, and set up lots of little stacks that nest under a parent stack. Mostly, this is working fine; however, in an intermediate stack I've now exceeded the max 60 parameter count. This will only get worse when I go the next level up and aggregate these intermediate stacks into a master parent stack.

The CloudFormation documentation says, "To specify more parameters, you can use mappings or lists in order to assign multiple values to a single parameter." In fact, that exact quotation has been given at least twice here in response to the 60 parameter limit question. However, *how* does one go about doing that? I can see how the mapping capability could work when you're selecting from a bunch of pre-defined sets of values (e.g., select from these AMI IDs, or these subnets), but don't see how it could work when the parameters are strings or numbers or other user-entered data; and I can't see an example at all of how lists do it.

Does anyone have an example or two of how they've used mappings and or lists to consolidate multiple user-entered parameters into a single parameter?

*Edit*, per a request in comments, I'm adding more details on what my templates look like. Here is the ParameterGroups section of the parent stack in question. It rolls up nested stacks for "mail storage" (which creates EBS volumes), "mail" which launches a primary and backup MX server and configures Postfix, Dovecot, etc..., and "Roundcube" which launches a autoscaling group of web servers running roundcube. All of this sits on top of another nested stack, "infrastructure", which deploys VPC, Subnets, ELB, NAT, RDS, security groups, and phpmyadmin.

```
 AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      -
        Label:
          default: Mandatory Parameters
        Parameters:
          - Vpc
          - NumberOfAZs
          - AvailabilityZones
          - AMIID
          - WantRoundCube
      -
        Label:
          default: Recommended Parameters
        Parameters:
          - AdminUser
          - AdminPubKey
      -
        Label:
          default: Mail Storage Parameters
        Parameters:
          - SpoolSize
          - LogSize
          - CreateSwap
          - SwwapSize
          - EncryptedBoolean
          - Cmk
          - SpoolDelPolicy
          - LogDelPolicy
          - MasterSpoolSnapshot
          - MasterLogSnapshot
          - BackupSpoolSnapshot
          - BackupLogSnapshot
      -
        Label:
          default: Primary MX EC2 Instance Parameters
        Parameters:
          - PrimaryServerName
          - VirtualUID
          - EC2KeyName
          - MailInstanceType
          - MailSecurityGroup
          - StorageStackName
          - PrimarySubnet
          - InsertTestData
      -
        Label:
         default: Backup MX EC2 Instance Parameters
        Parameters:
          - BackupServerName
          - BackupMailInstanceType
          - BackupSubnet
      -
        Label:
          default: Database Parameters
        Parameters:
          - DatabaseStackName
          - MailDBName
          - MailDBUser
          - MailDBPassword
          - MailDBBackup
      -
        Label:
          default: Postfix Primary Parameters
        Parameters:
          - Origin
          - Banner
          - RelayHost
          - RootMailRecipient
          - InetProtocols
          - EnableSpfChecks
          - EnableOpenDkim
          - OpenDkimDomains
      -
        Label:
          default: SSL Parameters
        Parameters:
          - CertSource
          - AccountEmail
          - DNSZone
          - DNSSleep
          - CertFileDir
      -
        Label:
          default: Dovecot Parameters
        Parameters:
          - MaxUserConnections
      -
        Label:
          default: Amavisd, SpamAssassin, ClamAV
        Parameters:
          - SAFinalDest
          - SAKillLevelDeflt
          - SetMyHost
     -
        Label:
          default: Roundcube
        Parameters:
          - AllowPasswdChange
          - AlternativeIAMRole
          - AlternativeInitializationScript
          - DnsName
          - EnableDebug
          - EnvironmentVariables
          - Hash
          - PublicAlbListenerArn
          - RoundcubeDBName
          - RoundcubeDBUser
          - RoundcubeDBPass
          - RoundcubeInstanceType
          - RoundcubeSecurityGroup
          - Skin
      -
        Label:
          default: AWS S3 Configuration
        Parameters:
          - MirovoyCFAssetsBucket
          - MailS3KeyPrefix
          - RoundcubeS3KeyPrefix
          - SkelFileDir
      - Label:
          default: Testing Configuration
        Parameters:
          - UnknownLocalErrorCode
          - XandrosPass
          - VivitaPass
          - ExternalTestEmail
          - SSLDebug
          - ADLogLevel
          - DisableVirusChecks
          - DisableSpamChecks
          - DisableServices
      -
        Label:
          default: Postfix Optional Parameters
        Parameters:
          - DelayWarningTime
          - MaxQueueLifetime
          - MinBackoffTime
         - MaxBackoffTime
          - HeloTimeout
          - RecipientLimit
          - SoftErrLimit
          - HardErrLimit
          - SpfTimeLimit
```

I'm happy to post more of the template as necessary, but it's obviously already getting quite long :)

Thanks!

Comment: The number of parameters you're using sounds pretty high to me. Can you post an example of how you use CloudFormation templates?

Comment: Well, I kind of agree :) I suspect I'm missing some architectural understanding of how to use nested stacks. Post updated to include example.

Comment: `I'm trying to follow AWS CloudFormation best practices, and set up lots of little stacks that nest under a parent stack.`

I don’t believe that is part of CloudFormation best practices. Nested stacks should be used for common patterns that you want to reuse: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#nested

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I don't know where I got that idea from exactly, nor how I slightly misinterpreted it, but I still don't think my goal is wrong. If I look at the AWS reference architectures (e.g., https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-refarch-wordpress or https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-refarch-continuous-deployment), I still think what I'm trying to do is the correct thing (though maybe not for the reason stated).

Comment: Or should I not be trying to roll up these patterns ("mail server", "storage", etc...) into a parent stack, and just be deploying them individually?